# Moving the first line of a textarea onto a field with a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
create table a ( ta text, f1 char(128), f2 char(128) );
```

With data:

```
insert into a values ("line 1 for first record\nThis is the rest of the body\nLike this", "");
insert into a values ("line 1 for second record\nThis is the rest of the body again\nLike this", "");
```

I need a query that will:

- Delete the first line out of `ta`
- Place that first line into `f1`

The query would need to change this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
| ta                                                                    | f1   |f2    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
|line 1 for first record\nThis is the rest of the body\nLike this       |      |      |
|line 1 for second record\nThis is the rest of the body again\nLike this|      |      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
```

Into this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+------------------------+------+------+
| ta                                           | f1                            |f2    |
+----------------------------------------------+------------------------+------+------+
|This is the rest of the body\nLike this       |line 1 for first record        |      |
|This is the rest of the body again\nLike this |line 1 for second record       |      |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------+
```

I spent way too long trying unsuccessfully. I am just about ready to give up.

Is there an easy reliable way to do that?

**BONUS QUESTION:**
Could you extend the answer so that the first line goes to `f1` and the second line goes to `f2`?

So the result would be:

```
+------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+
| ta         |f1                      |f2                                |
+------------+------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
|\nLike this |line 1 for first record |This is the rest of the body      |
|\nLike this |line 1 for second record|This is the rest of the body again|
+------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: ahh.. I see. So the separator (or delimiter) is always `\n`, correct? Are there any variant of the data that we need to be aware of? Like what kind of data not qualified to be inserted to what column? For example if the data instead is like this `line 1 for first record\nLike this`, how would it be inserted? Or there's no possibility that the data format will be different, simply there's no other variant.

Comment: Separator is always \n and no sanity checking required

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), I find it possible by combining various [`substring`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), [`length`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_length) and [`substring_index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```sql
-- INSERT INTO `a` ...

UPDATE `a` SET
    `f1`=substring_index(`ta`,"\n",1),
    `f2`=substring_index(substring_index(`ta`,"\n",2),"\n",-1),
    `ta`=substring(`ta` FROM length(substring_index(`ta`,"\n",2))+1);
```

explain:

- `f1` line extract the text before the first `\n`;
- `f2` line extract the text before the second `\n`, and then extract the result after the last `\n`;
- `ta` line use `length` and `substring` to get the leftover

[online fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nuGSdZE5Ui9Kd9DCMYNsZy/0)

The order after `SET` is important (at least in the fiddle), `ta` must update last, or `f1` and `f2` would get undesired result.

It would be more clean and clear if it's possible to write two or three query instead of one, but the idea should be the same.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I hope this will help others in the future...!

Comment: Will this puke if `ta` is null or empty? Should I add `WHERE ta is not NULL AND where ta <> ''`?

Comment: @Merc Empty should be OK, `substring_index('')` just return empty string; but `NULL` might be a problem. Maybe you should add `WHERE ta IS NOT NULL`